# Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY - GSON kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I'm fairly new to JSON parsing, I'm using the Retrofit library of Square and ran into this problem.

I'm trying to parse this JSON reponse:

```
[{
"contactName":"ABC",
"addons":[
{"vasCode":"GTG021","propCode":"PROP0044","propValue":"0","fieldName":null},
{"vasCode":"GTG021","propCode":"PROP0043","propValue":"175000","fieldName":null},
{"vasCode":"GTG021","propCode":"PROP0018","propValue":"175000","fieldName":"COD_AMOUNT"},
{"vasCode":"GTG021","propCode":"PROP0019","propValue":"1","fieldName":"PAID_TYPE_COD"},
{"vasCode":"GTG021","propCode":"PROP0022","propValue":null,"fieldName":"BRANCH_NAME"},
{"vasCode":"GTG021","propCode":"PROP0021","propValue":null,"fieldName":"BANK_NAME"},
{"vasCode":"GTG021","propCode":"PROP0020","propValue":null,"fieldName":"ACCOUNT_NUMBER_COD"}],
"packages":"250000"
}]
```

Here are my models:

```kotlin
data class Contacts {
    @SerializedName("contactName") var contactName: String,
    @SerializedName("addons") var addons: ArrayList<Addons>,
    @SerializedName("packages") var packages: String,
}

data class Addons {
    @SerializedName("vasCode") var vasCode: String,
    @SerializedName("propCode") var propCode: String,
    @SerializedName("propValue") var propValue: String,
    @SerializedName("fieldName") var fieldName: String,
}
```

my Interface:

```kotlin
interface GetItemData {

    @GET("searchTtNumber?mode=API")
    fun getItem(
        @Header("authorization") authorization: String,
        @Query("ttNumber") ttNumber: String,
        @Query("orgCode") orgCode: String
    ): Call<ArrayList<Contacts>>
}
```

My Retrofit builder

```kotlin
object RetrofitHelperItem {
    fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://something/") // Base URL of the API
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}
```

My class to request data

```kotlin
class ItemData(private val key : String,private val bien : String,private val orgCode : String) {
    
    // Create the ApiService instance using the Retrofit instance
    private val apiServiceItem = RetrofitHelperItem.getInstance().create(GetItemData::class.java)

    private var dt : ArrayList<Contacts>? = null
    suspend fun getItemData() : ArrayList<Contacts>? {
        try {
            val response = apiServiceItem.getItem(key, bien, orgCode).execute()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                dt = response.body()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return dt
    }
}
```

And the err was `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2075 path $[0].packages`

Have been looking around all day but sill no luck. I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you please provide a more detailed error log to confirm the level of the issue? However,  I have tried a mock retrofit response and it's working fine. Also, make sure if  you are getting the correct response.

Comment: I just updated the full error. The JSON response that I posted is the response I got when I use Call<response> in interface instead of using my model

Comment: @HaTr, could you please add the complete JSON data and your classes to the question? The exception message mentions a JSON member called 'packages', but neither your JSON data nor your classes contain it (I assume you omitted it here). Or if the JSON data is too large at least include the 'packages' member and the respective code in your `Contacts` class.

Comment: @Marcono1234 Thank you, I'm so dumb, I thought packages was some actual package files somewhere, didn't even realise there's a JSON member called 'packages'. And yes, the complete JSON is like 400+ lines.

Comment: @Marcono1234 The 'packages' from the JSON response behave very unexpectedly, when it has value, it returns a string like "1231" but when it doesn't, it return [] like an array. No wonder my code does work time to time

Comment: Surely, the issue is the value of ```packages``` in response. This should be fixed from the API end. However, you can currently declare ```packages``` type as ```Any```. When you want to use this value you can check if it's a String then use it else empty.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved yep, I was thinking about making 2 data classes and check the `packages` before parsing but your solution works better. Thanks!

Comment: Have voted to close this a duplicate because the other question is pretty similar (or maybe even the same). If the `packages` field has a JSON array as value, will it only ever be empty, or could it actually have more than one value? In that case this is very likely a duplicate and your property should have type `List<String>`.

Comment: @Marcono1234 'packages' will only be array when it's empty and switch to string when has value. I took a look at the other question and it looks like the proper solution for me. Thanks!